# PL/SQL procedure call in Java

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, plsql

DB beginner here.
I have a procedure called "mkdir" that's supposed to mimic the bash command:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE "MKDIR" 
(
  id_p in number
, name in varchar2  
) as 
begin
  insert into folders(name,id_p) values(name,id_p);
  dbms_output.put_line('Created folder: '||name);

exception
when DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX then
  dbms_output.put_line('Folder with the same name already exists!');
when NO_DATA_FOUND then
  dbms_output.put_line('Parent id not found!');

end mkdir;
```

Heres part of my Java program:

```
String sql = "begin mkdir(var1=>?, " +"var2=>?); end;";

st = conn.prepareCall(sql);
st.setInt(1,1);             
st.setString(2, "hello");

st.execute();
```

I've tried switching the order of variables, but it doesn't work. I realise this is an extremely stupid error, but i can't for the life of me resolve it.

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'MKDIR'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be
String sql = "exec mkdir .......

Comment: Nope, it gets to the mkdir procedure, as in it's called, then the error is thrown from inside the procedure itself.

Comment: is it because your column name and procedure parameter name is same... try renaming the proc parameter name

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
String sql="begin mkdir(var1=>?, " +"var2=>?); end;";
```

Your stored procedure does not take parameters named `var1` and `var2`.  You are getting the error because you are attempting to provide values for these nonexistent procedure parameters.

Try

```
String sql="begin mkdir(id_p=>?, " +"name=>?); end;";
```

instead.